# $\mod 4$ properties of Fermat number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $k\in\Bbb N$.
Let $2^{2^k}+1$ be a composite Fermat number.
Let $p$ be a prime factor of $2^{2^k}+1$.
Then is $p\mod 4\equiv 1$?

Comment: Yes, you even have $p \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{k+2}}$.

Comment: proof please:)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is a prime divisor of $F_k = 2^{2^k}+1$, then we have

$$2^{2^k} \equiv -1 \pmod{p},$$

hence $2^{2^{k+1}} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and the order of $2$ modulo $p$ is $2^{k+1}$. That directly yields $2^{k+1} \mid (p-1)$ or, expressed differently, $p \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{k+1}}$. But, since $k > 4$, as we assumed $F_k$ to be composite, that means in particular $p \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, and hence $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. Let $x^2\equiv 2 \pmod{p}$. Then the order of $x$ modulo $p$ is $2^{k+2}$, and hence $p \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{k+2}}$.